# Use Solr with PDF files

Tags: pdf, solr, solrnet

I want to use Solr with PDF files, but I don’t know how configure solrconfig.xml and schema.xml. What should I write in those file ? The aim is to do full-text search with synonym or spell checker for example.(I use Solr on Windows, and in the future i will use the API SolrNet).Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [Tika](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html) to extract text from a PDF file.

- Tika extracts metadata from the PDF document, for `title`,
  `author`, and so on. As such, your schema should include fields for
  `title` and `author`.
- Tika extracts the body of the PDF document to the `content` field, so
  your schema should also include a `content` field.

Once Tika is configured, you issue a HTTP POST to Solr, specifying the PDF file you wish to index:

`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true' -F "myfile=@example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf"`

If you need to map the fields Tika generates (`title`, `author`, `content`) to different fields in your Solr index, you can use the `fmap` feature:

`fmap.content=text` would map Tika's extracted `content` field to Solr's `text` field.